# Remove element jquery with a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove a specific row with a unique id when the user click on a delete img. It does not work when i select 'tr#'+id and then remove.

Here is my code

js

```
$("#page_body").on('click', 'a.delete_line', function(e) {
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    $('tr#'+id).remove(); 
});
```

html

```
<tr id="unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename">
<td class="value">ANY</td><td class="value">MAIN </td>
<td class="value">false</td>
<td class="value">unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename</td>
<td class="value">unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.txt</td>
<td class="value">undefined</td>
<td><a href="#" class="delete_line" id="unitesbudg_roic_assetcenter.V01.aaf.filename"><img src="img/delete.png"></a></td>
</tr>
```

Also if you can advice me on best practices for such a feature.

Thx a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery should look something more like this:

```
$("#page_body").on('click', 'a.delete_line', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML `IDs` must be unique. You can use `.closest()` to find the parent **tr**

Just use

```
 $(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypEk9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
   $('#page_body tr:last').remove();
```